# Flex error when removing child

Tags: apache-flex

Have a rather bizarre issue with Flex throwing an error when teh application is running in the background.  I use Selenium and SeleniumFlexApi to run various tests against my app.  If the browser window is in the foreground or any part of it is visible to teh screen, the test pass as expected.  However, if the window is in the background and not visible, I am getting the following error in 1 part of my app.

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

I have a VBOX that creates a number of children and then upon creationComplete(or UpdateComplete, I've tried both) it then needs to remove any of the children that are not visible.  Each child has a listener for CreationComplete which checks if the child is visible and if not, adds it to an array which is iterated over when the parent UpdateComplete is fired.  I cant seem to find any reason for this behavior and am curious if its an issue with the Flex Component LifeCycle.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version of the Flash Player (10.1) will automatically "slow down" when minimized.  I think it drops to a couple of frames a minute [as opposed to the standard 24 per second for Flex].  I don't know specific number.s  This is for performance and 'battery life' reasons.

If there is anything in your app, or in your testing, that requires specific timing or uses a timer, then this will easily break unit tests.

I've heard from other folks that this have other folks that have had issues with this. The best solution I've heard proposed is "Add a flag to turn this off; even if it's only in the debug player."  But, there is no solution right now other than "run your tests w/o the app minimized"

Comment: +1, I was thinking the same thing but couldn't articulate it as well as you did.